# joomla flv player

Tags: php, joomla, flvplayback

I need the possibility to add videos to an article, do you know about something that might be usable? Only thing I need is just that it will be able to play flv video. I found HDFLV player, which is pretty fine but it cannot be used in an article, unless you buy it for like 99$, which is unacceptable.

Thanks,
EL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Flow Player](http://flowplayer.org/setup/index.html).
Its free and easy to install. You can customise various options using a UI on their site and they will provide the embed code for it.

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 might be usable.
http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/video.html

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here: http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/multimedia/multimedia-players. 
The extensions are evaluated. Some are free.

Answer (score 0):

hey the best one imo is >>

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/multimedia/multimedia-players/video-players-a-gallery/3955?qh=YTo2OntpOjA7czozOiJhbGwiO2k6MTtzOjQ6ImFsbGUiO2k6MjtzOjU6ImFsbGVzIjtpOjM7czo1OiJ2aWRlbyI7aTo0O3M6NjoidmlkZW9zIjtpOjU7czo5OiJhbGwgdmlkZW8iO30%3D

its easy to use and configure and non-commercial